# Cannot POST /api/user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am testing a user registration route but its returning a Cannot POST /api/user and it seems i can't pin point the problems.
when I run a get request using postman, it works...but when I post, it returns a Cannot POST /api/user result .

Any sort of help/response will be greatly appreciated.

here is my server.js file.

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongosse = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//const entries = require('./routes/api/entries');
const app = express();
const path = require("path")

//app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.json())
//const db = require('./config/keys.js').mongoURI;
mongosse
    .connect('mongodb+srv://user:pass2i8y7@gytay.qpgpm.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
        {
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useCreateIndex:true
        })
    .then(() => console.log('its connected'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

app.use('/api/entries', require('./routes/api/entries'));
app.use('/api/user', require('./routes/api/user'));

//serve a static dish of data
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {
    //set static folder
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,
            'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

And here is my User route.

```js
const express = require('express');
const router__ = express.Router();


//User model
const User = require('../../models/User');

//@Post api/users
//@desc register user/s

router__.post('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('regesiter__here');

});

module.exports = router__;
```

Comment: @ggorlen those are false..thank you

Comment: Why does `const router__ = express.Router();` have two `__` in it, but `router_.post('/', (req, res) => {...})` has one `_` in it?

Comment: @jfriend00 i just changed that but am still getting the same error

Comment: What result do you get when you do a GET to `/api/user`?  I ask because your `./routes/api/user` router shows no handler for any GET request, but something later might be handling it.

Comment: I'd suggest adding this code right before your `app.use('/api/user', ...)`.  Add `app.use('/api/user', (req, res, next) => { console.log(\`Got /api/user, ${req.method}\`); next(); })` and see if it outputs anything when you try the POST and the GET.

Comment: i made sure not to add a Get but when i accidentally changed to get in my post man and the result was "register" which was the first flag i used before changing it to "    res.send('regesiter__here')"

Comment: If that doesn't show anything, then add this: `app.use((req, res, next) => { console.log(\`Got ${req.method} request for ${req.originalUrl}\`); next(); })`.  This will log all requests so you can see what Express thinks it is getting.  Put this as the first middleware on your server.

Comment: still nothing shown on the logs

Comment: Nothing shown in the logs for the first suggestion or the second one?  The second one is supposed to log ALL requests so you're doing something major wrong if it shows nothing.  Perhaps your request from POSTMAN is defective and isn't even going to your server.  Or there's something else in your server that you're not showing us that is intercepting everything.

Comment: that actually everything to my server...i took out all middlewares and kept this app.use((req, res, next) => { console.log(`Got ${req.method} request for ${req.originalUrl}`); next(); }) but i can't find any logs

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any problem with the code so, i ended up restarting the server and it worked! everything good

Comment: How could you not have been restarting the server EVERY time I suggested you add some new debug code?  New code never takes effect until you restart the server.

Comment: it was restarting alright, but I had to real disconnect and reconnect